# Finding the largest word in a 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

```
package largestvalue;

import java.util.*;

public class LargestValue {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String array[][]={
      {"renas","Mahdy","Rezhwan"},
      {"HRashid","Barham","Harem"},
      {"zalamek","Mustafa","Sarbast"}
    };

    String Largest=array[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
        if (Largest < array[i][j]) { //This is the error
          Largest = array[i][j] + "";
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println("The Largest Number int the Array is :"+Largest);
  }
}
```

See screenshot of the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m71Zv.png).

Comment: you want to compare `String#length` against each other. There is no such operator as smaller or bigger for a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare Strings with `<` operator.

Change

```
if(Largest<array[i][j])
```

to

```
if(Largest.compareTo(array[i][j])<0)
```

Note that this will give you the "largest" `String` according to lexicographical (alphabetical) order, which is the natural order of `String`s in Java.

If, on the other hand, you want to find the longest `String`, that's a different thing, which would require comparing the `length()`s of the `String`s.

Comment: @renasahmad: If you find the answer posted by Eran is useful, Please accept his answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this:

```
 if(Largest<array[i][j])
```

With using `length()` method like below:

```
 if(Largest.length() < array[i][j].length())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "...";
int counter = 0;
for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ) {
    if( s.charAt(i) == '$' ) {
        counter++;
    } 
}
```

you could use the above code then assign counter to a variable designated for each value of your array then compare them. But I think it would be way too long to do.

Comment: I hope it gives you idea.

Comment: counter of length of string.

Comment: This neither works with an array nor does it compare string lengths. What's the point of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

```
String largest = Arrays.stream(array)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed())
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```